# Will an evaporation water cooler work better if the water in the reservoir is cool?

Tags: water, evaporation

I d like to find out if a evaporation water cooler works better or worse if you cool the water in the reservoir.
Let's suppose that the water in the reservoir is at some 10°C, will the cooler deliver colder air rather than if the water is at 50°C?

Answer (score 0):

pre-chilling the feed water to an evaporative cooler will increase the cooling, and this effect is commonly calculated when designing what are called *air-wash* cooling systems. The TRANE handbook of air conditioning contains a chart which allows prediction of the total cooling effect of pre-chilled feed water in an air wash cooling system, as functions of air flow rate, water flow rate, dew point temperature and air inlet temperature.